# How to check if array of objects that contains another array of object has property

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, object

Hi I have an array of objects which contains another array of objects.
I need to find an object in array which contains another object in it's array with certain propery
ID.
Let's say i need to find an object in `casses` array which contains a user with certain ID.
ID for user is unique.

```
  casses = [
       {
        caseName: 'case 1',
        date: '2021-05-4',
        id: '123',
        user: [{name: 'Vlad', id: '1'}, {name: 'Misha', id: '2'}]
       },
       {
        caseName: 'case 2',
        date: '2021-05-4',
        id: '123',
        user: [{name: 'Alina', id: '3'}, {name: 'Alex', id: '4'}]
       },
       {
        caseName: 'case 3',
        date: '2021-05-4',
        id: '123',
        user: []
       },
    ]
```

I could use a nested loops and so on. But i wondering is it possible to do with one line ?
Something like this but one level deeper:

```
let val = casses(item => item.id === element.id); ​
```

Comment: Nested loops is a good idea. You can usually then replace loops with builtin functions, that take over the looping, e.g. `Array.prototype.find` or `Array.prototype.some`, but accordingly, you'll need nested ones: `casses.find(outerObject => outerObject.user.some(user => user.id === '1'));`

Comment: I would like to use loops myself, they are much  easy to read and understand.
But  my task was to do it in very few lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume your case with `ID` set to "3"

Try below

```
const ID = "3";

const casses = [
    {
        caseName: "case 1",
        date: "2021-05-4",
        id: "123",
        user: [
            { name: "Vlad", id: "1" },
            { name: "Misha", id: "2" }
        ]
    },
    {
        caseName: "case 2",
        date: "2021-05-4",
        id: "123",
        user: [
            { name: "Alina", id: "3" },
            { name: "Alex", id: "4" }
        ]
    },
    {
        caseName: "case 3",
        date: "2021-05-4",
        id: "123",
        user: []
    }
];

casses.find(item => item.user.some(subItem => subItem.id === ID));
```

Comment: @Vlad, check this out!!

Comment: Thank you so much for a great answer), it helped me a lot!

Comment: If not using build in function, how can I quickly locate it? If using for loop I have to go over all then it is not inefficient.

Comment: using built-in functions is cleaner than using for loops and they are already efficient as some and find method stops looping after finding the first match. You will have to add that logic within loops as well.